# Using Javascript in Qualtrics to Embed Data from a Response Option

Tags: javascript, embedding, survey, qualtrics

My goal is to randomize 10 items within a block, and then ask a series of questions about the last item displayed. I got JS to work for the item stem, but not for the response option that was selected.

I begin by defining the embedded data at the beginning of the survey.

[image]

Next, I add JS for each question in the first block. Labeling them with the same embedded name causes Qualtrics to overwrite the embedded data each time, which means that it will remember the last question displayed from the first block:

JS for Q1 (note that it calls QID1):

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    
    var text = "${q://QID1/QuestionText}";
    
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'TestQuestion', text );
    
    var answer = "${q://QID1/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}";
    
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( "TestAnswer", answer );


});
```

JS for Q2 (note that it calls QID2):

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    
    var text = "${q://QID2/QuestionText}";
    
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'TestQuestion', text );
    
    var answer = "${q://QID2/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}";
    
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( "TestAnswer", answer );


});
```

Next, I call the embedded data in the subsequent block in the questions:

[image]

However, when I launch the survey, it only displays the TestQuestion metadata:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How can I get the response option (TestAnswer embedded data) to pipe in? Should it be added at a different spot in the JS?**

I also tried this, but it didn't work:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageSubmit(function(type)
{
    if(type == "next")
        
    {var answer = "${q://QID2/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}";
    
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( "TestAnswer", answer );}
    
});
```

Comment: I have removed the incorrect tag "embedded" from your post.  When you type a tag a description appears which shows what it is for, so please take care when adding tags in future.  "embedded" is for embedded microcontrollers etc, not embedding data in something.

Comment: Answered here: https://community.qualtrics.com/XMcommunity/discussion/19809/using-js-to-embed-data-in-individual-items-response-options